# How access WindowManager "private" properties?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-windowmanager

Read [this chinese article](https://blog.xzr.moe/archives/136/) that explain how is possible hide a window from screenshot through:

```
WindowLayoutParams.privateFlags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.PRIVATE_FLAG_IS_ROUNDED_CORNERS_OVERLAY;
```

but i not able to access this property and constant from Visual Studio:

[image]

---

[image]

How achieve this?

There's some related tutorial available on web?

Comment: In which language are you doing code for mobile application?

Comment: Those flags are for system apps. this requires your app to be a system app to access those APIs.

Comment: @Zain, then basically to access these APIs, i need download AOSP, compile generating a new *android.jar* and replace *android.jar* that already exists on VS folder?

Comment: Sorry, I have not tried that before; probably you can Google something like "How to create android system app"

Answer (score 0):

The author of that blog is referred to `WindowStateAnimator.java` inside of the code, but as I've searched there is no such flag in [WindowStateAnimator.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a029ea1/services/java/com/android/server/wm/WindowStateAnimator.java) or in [2014 version](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/153fa99/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/WindowStateAnimator.java).

The correct one must be something like below:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        mWindowLayoutParams.flags |=
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
```

I couldn't find property `.privateFlags`, instead there is a similar `.flags` property. Also I couldn't find property `.PRIVATE_FLAG_IS_ROUNDED_CORNERS_OVERLAY` for `LayoutParams`.

Also I've tried to import that flag using

```
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.PRIVATE_FLAG_IS_ROUNDED_CORNERS_OVERLAY;
```

But there is no such package!

But I belive it has been defined as (try it!) [see android source for instance](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/WindowManager.java)

```
public static final int PRIVATE_FLAG_IS_ROUNDED_CORNERS_OVERLAY = 0x00100000;
```